# Comparing elements in an 2D array

Tags: java

I created the following table using [jtextUtils](https://code.google.com/p/j-text-utils/)

Now I want to do the following for every row,

if every column, starting at column 3 are equal to each other, write an "x" to the "False?" column.

[image: table]

This is the 2D array I have, it is already filled with elements:

```
String [][] cPosTags = new String[x][y];
```

Comment: This is really unclear...

Comment: You are right, i forgot to link something.

Comment: That doesn't help much...

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll try to explain again: for example in row 1, in each column starting at the third there is "DT". That means, do not mark a cross in column 2. That's the way i want to compare the table.

Comment: So if columns 3-5 are equal you write an "x" to column 2?

Comment: Correct :) and i want to do that for each row. Or in other words: Compare if all elements in a row are equal (excluding column 1 & 2)

Comment: Updated my answer, if it answers your question consider accepting it as an answer.

Comment: Glad to help, you should accept it to inform future viewers that it works.

Comment: Stack Overflow tip: Take the time to format your questions and make them clear. The answerer needs to be able to look at it and understand it easily...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

Try this:

```
for (int i=0;i<cPosTags.length;i++) {
    boolean equal = true;
    for (int j=4;j<cPosTags[i].length) {
        if (!cPosTags[i][3].equals(cPosTags[i][j])) {
            equal = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!equal)
        cPosTags[i][2] = "x";
}
```

I might be mixing up rows and columns...

---

Your question is really unclear, but you can iterate through the array and compare elements:

Iteration:

```
for (int i=0;i<cPosTags.length;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<cPosTags[i].length) {

    }
}
```

Comparison:

```
cPosTags[3][3].equals("hello");
cPosTags[3][5].equals(cPosTags[3][4]);
```